# Python Selenium problems with get_attribute('innerHTML')

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

I'm having some problems with retrieving innerHTML of multiple elements in Python with Selenium.

When I retrieve the data from one element this works perfectly with the following code:

```
productid0 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("mod-article-tile__meta")
productid1 = productid0.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

From the moment I change element to elementS then my code doesn't work anymore and I get the following error *"AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'"*:

```
productid0 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("mod-article-tile__meta")
productid1 = productid0.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

I need to use the elements as I want to get this from all my elements on a specific page.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_element_by_class_name` returns an element, but `find_elements_by_class_name` returns a *list of elements*. Like the error suggests you are calling `get_attribute()` on a Python `list`, which is not a thing. You have to specify an element in that list:

```
products = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("mod-article-tile__meta")
# get the innerhtml of the first element in the list
innerhtml = products[0].get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Answer (score 1):

### What happens?

`find_elements_by_class_name` creates a list of all matches and that is why you could not access the `innerHTML` directly

### How to fix that?

Loop over the list and get the `innerHTML` of each match:

```
for product in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("mod-article-tile__meta"):
    product.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the productid0.

```
productid0 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("mod-article-tile__meta")
for product in product0:
    print(product.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part where you use `find_element_by_class_name("mod-article-tile__meta")`just returns you the first element with class name "mod-article-tile__meta" whereas `find_elements_by_class_name("mod-article-tile__meta")` returns you a list of elements with the class name "mod-article-tile__meta".

To use the elements you have to iterate through the list and call get_attribute on each member of the list.

```py
productid0 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("mod-article-tile__meta")
productid1 = list(map(lambda p: p.get_attribute('innerHTML') , productid0))
```

The above code is can be written as a for loop as well

```py
productid0 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("mod-article-tile__meta")
productid1 = []

for p0 in productid0:
    productid1.append(p0.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```